# Python threading - Program finishes up immediately after execution

Tags: python, multithreading, class, python-multithreading

I saw many questions and follow their answers but for some reason, my program ends without even doing the threads

```
send_to_server = SendToServer(send_request_to)
        send_computer_details = threading.Thread(target=send_to_server.send_computer_details, args=[ProcessDetail, CpuDetail, MemoryDetail])
        send_dir_files = threading.Thread(target=send_to_server.send_dir_files)
        send_computer_details.setDaemon(True)
        send_dir_files.setDaemon(True)
        send_computer_details.start()
        send_dir_files.start()
```

For some reason when I try to run the code it ends immediately without really doing the while True loop I have in there I can't really understand why.

Comment: Only the main thread is non-daemon so the others end when main thread ends (nearly immediately).

Comment: @MichaelButscher So what do I need to do?

Comment: Under which condition(s) should the program end? Only manually by Ctrl-C, after some time elapsed?

Comment: @MichaelButscher ctrl-c

Comment: Try to not set at least one of the other threads as daemon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple: thanks to Michel Butscher I figured out that I need to put one of the threads in daemon so it will keep ongoing not both. So by removing one, it solved it

```
send_to_server = SendToServer(send_request_to)
        send_computer_details = threading.Thread(target=send_to_server.send_computer_details, args=[ProcessDetail, CpuDetail, MemoryDetail])
        send_dir_files = threading.Thread(target=send_to_server.send_dir_files)
        send_computer_details.setDaemon(True)
        send_computer_details.start()
        send_dir_files.start()
```